# How do I avoid using a for-loop to get elements of a nested list to the top level?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-lists

I am trying to extract the coefficients of a set of linear models into a data frame. How do I extract these values without using a for-loop?

The data in my example is dummy data for clarity. The actual project makes models for air temperature for each day of the year, and then tries to model the parameters of these models. Currently I can only accumulate each coefficient in a separate variable, and then apply individually it to my data set:

```
require(tidyverse)

# making different mpg models from displacement, distinguished by cylinder count
models <- mtcars %>% 
  nest(-cyl, .key = "cardata") %>% 
  mutate(mod = map(cardata, ~lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .))) %>% 
  mutate(coefficients = map(mod, coefficients))    #this only extracts a list of coefficients

# currently using one for-loop to extract each coefficient, looking for a more elegant way...
coef.intercept <- c()
for (i in models$coefficients) {
  coef.intercept <- c(coef.intercept,i[1])
}

coef.disp <- c()
for (i in models$coefficients) {
  coef.disp <- c(coef.disp,i[2])
}

# putting together the final data frame
models <- models %>% 
  mutate(coef.intercept) %>% 
  mutate(coef.disp) %>% 
  select(cyl, coef.intercept, coef.disp) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

Using 'map' I can extract a list of coefficients, but I cannot use the '[' operator in order to get specific elements of the individual lists. Something like

```
mutate(models, coef.intercept = map(models, coefficients[1]))
```

does not work, I get "Error: Index 1 must have length 1, not 2".

Comment: I'm far from my computer now, but for a list `A` you can do `sapply(A, '[[', 1)` to extract first element. Both `[` and `[[` are functions, even if they don't appear to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able at the moment to replicate your example, but I think you can start from here and adapt this solution to your needs.

```
A <- list(a = list(1,"j"), b = list(2, "k") ,  d = list(3, "m" ) ) 

sapply(A, `[[`, 1)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!